# Can't remove gem from rvm gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

It seems like I installed the `rails 4.2` and `rails 5.0.1` in the same `gemset`. Now I want to delete the version `5.0.1`.

Here is what I did.

```
> rvm use 2.3.2@rails420
> gem uninstall rails --version 5.0.1
> rails -v
Rails 5.0.1
```

I am confused why it still exist?

Comment: did you switch in and out of the directory and then try `rails -v`?

Answer (score 0):

Gemset's version of rails must not be the one you have running on your machine and backwards. Check the overall rails version and the gemset entry.

Comment: Sorry, what's the exact thing I need to do? I am in `2.3.2@rails420`.